# Difference between dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script for members and it has 2 tables (`users` and `msgs`).

I want to get the top member for posting messages per day. I used this code but it is not working:

```
$start = TIMENOW - TIMENOW % 86400;
$end = $start + 86400;
$maxposter = mysql_query("SELECT users.name,users.id,count(*) total FROM users AS users,msgs AS msgs WHERE users.id=msgs.userid AND msgs.added_date BETWEEN $start AND $end GROUP BY msgs.userid ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
$maxmsg=mysql_fetch_assoc($maxposter);
echo $maxmsg[name];
```

The row `added_date` is being stored like `2011-05-05`.

Comment: Explain how it is "not working".

Comment: the added_date always like ( 05-05-2011 ) and the $start & $end varuables are between 0 - 86400;

Answer (score 1):

instead that , try

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2011-05-05', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: also see  `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)` and `DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)`

Comment: @Pin looking at your question history, you need to start learning fundamental basics first.